# Xamarin BLE messes up received bytes

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently working on a App written in Xamarin.Forms that communicates with an ESP Device via BLE.
I got it communicating already and I also could send some Data to the Device and even receive it.

When i try to receive a little longer piece of configuration though, the beginning of the message is kinda messed up. The deformation of the message seems deterministic, since it's always wrong in the same way.

I receive the message like follows:

```
    async private Task<string> ReadDeviceConfiguration(IDevice device) {
        ICharacteristic characteristic = await GetCharacteristic(device, WTServiceUUIDs.CHARACT_CONFIG);
        if (characteristic.CanRead) {
            try {
                var bytes = await characteristic.ReadAsync();
                var str = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
                return str;
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }



    private async Task<ICharacteristic> GetCharacteristic(IDevice device, Guid wtServiceCharacteristicUUID) {
        IService service = await device.GetServiceAsync(WTServiceUUIDs.SERVICE);
        if (service != null) {
            var characteristic = await service.GetCharacteristicAsync(wtServiceCharacteristicUUID);
            if (characteristic != null) {
                return characteristic;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The Message i want to receive starts like this:

> {"MODE":0,"DEVICE_ID":123456789,"DEVICE_NAME":"Test Name", ... etc

What i find instead is:

> {"DEVICE_NAME":"Test N123456789,"DEVICE_NAME":"Test Name", ... etc

basically the first part of the DEVICE_NAME followed by the value of DEVICE_ID. MODE ist completely omitted.

I looked into the byte array coming out of ReadAsync() (in case the encoding is going wrong) and it displays the same errors.

I also checked the output of my ESP Device using the nRF Connect App on my Android Phone and it displays the correct and expected message.

** **EDIT:** Removed an unrelated sidenote and i got an update:

I moved on a little and implemented a function, where i send some wifi infos to the ESP device which in return checks if the infos are correct and returns a result. if the results are OK, i request the config as described above and get the same error, BUT i realized the String that's at the beginning is part of the wifi information message i previously sent to the device.
I decided to request the config twice in a row and encode the bytes into a string and this is the result:

> {"TYPE":"WIFI_CHECK","123456789,"DEVICE_NAME":"Test Name", ... etc
>
> {"MODE":0,"DEVICE_ID":123456789,"DEVICE_NAME":"Test Name", ... etc

The first one to be the faulty message, the second one the message as i expected it.
So i figure there must be a buffer that wasn't cleared and in this case it occurs that it overrides the first 22 characters.
I can use that as a workaround but obviously that's not the solution.
There is no flush or clear method for the ICharacteristic interface. is there anything else i could to to avoid this problem?

I hope someone got a hint how to tackle that. thank you in advance.